# WPF - DataGrid limit row multiselect depending on first selection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, multipleselection

Curently I have datagrid which displays some custom class items which don't really matter here. I'm using a custom datagrid control that inherits `DataGrid`. This is because I'm using a MVVM model and I needed to implement bindable `SelectedItemsList`.

I've also implemented `CollectionViewSource` so I can group items by my desires.

Now the problem I'm having is that I need to limit users selection options after first item is selected..

Since I don't want to allow user selecting multiple rows in different data groups. Is there any elegant way? Because my idea is not ideal... (When selection occured I test if every element has a specific property of the same type).

I've tried to look it up on google, but untill now i couldn't find any good answers or maybe is my english knowledge too limited to "ask" the right question the allfriendly google.